# Regex: Matching dates with out a 0 in front of the month and data

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am currently working on a hw assignment dealing with Regex.

HW Objective:

Match any date of the form: mm/dd/yyyy, where mm and dd maybe 1 or 2 digit numbers,
but yyyy always contains 4 digits and the slashes are required. The mm field must correspond to a valid month (1 through 12) and the dd field to a valid date (1 through 31). The first two digits in the yyyy field must either be a "19" or a "20".

Ex: Matches 12/01/1922 and 2/4/2000 but not 12-01-1922 and 12/01/22

This what I currently have:

```
(0[1-9]|1[12])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[1])/((19|20)\d\d)
```

I am needing the Regex to match when there is no 0 in front of the day and month. It currently matches if I add a 0 to my test data.

I have tried adding another | for when there is not 1 or 0 in front, but it did not work

Comment: Are you aware that your regex doesn't match october, month `10`?

Answer (score 1):

Just make those zero's optional by adding a `?` after them:

```
(0?[1-9]|1[12])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[1])\/((19|20)\d\d)
```

this seems to work.

https://regex101.com/r/E05ahM/1/

You can also visit this for more information:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html